# Add to cart and redirect to checkout for default variable products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying the following code by LoicTheAztec - [Add to cart and redirect to checkout for variable products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865565/add-to-cart-and-redirect-to-checkout-for-variable-products-in-woocommerce)

Now, the problem is whenever I am clicking on the Buy Now button with the default variations set in the Product editor, the code is not working.

The Buy Now URL in this case becomes …/?addtocart=0&quantity=n

The Theme I am using - Basel

Any solutions?

Tried the code by LoicTheAztec.

````
function add_custom_addtocart_and_checkout() {
    global $product;

    $addtocart_url = wc_get_checkout_url().'?add-to-cart='.$product->get_id();
    $button_class  = 'single_add_to_cart_button button alt custom-checkout-btn';
    $button_text   = __("Buy & Checkout", "woocommerce");

    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' )) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var url    = '<?php echo $addtocart_url; ?>',
            qty    = 'input.qty',
            button = 'a.custom-checkout-btn';

        // On input/change quantity event
        $(qty).on('input change', function() {
            $(button).attr('href', url + '&quantity=' + $(this).val() );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) : 

    $addtocart_url = wc_get_checkout_url().'?add-to-cart=';
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var url    = '<?php echo $addtocart_url; ?>',
            vid    = 'input[name="variation_id"]',
            pid    = 'input[name="product_id"]',
            qty    = 'input.qty',
            button = 'a.custom-checkout-btn';

        // Once DOM is loaded
        setTimeout( function(){
            if( $(vid).val() != '' ){
                $(button).attr('href', url + $(vid).val() + '&quantity=' + $(qty).val() );
            }
        }, 300 );

        // On input/change quantity event
        $(qty).on('input change', function() {
            if( $(vid).val() != '' ){
                $(button).attr('href', url + $(vid).val() + '&quantity=' + $(this).val() );
            }
        });

        // On select attribute field change event
        $('.variations_form').on('change blur', 'table.variations select', function() {
            if( $(vid).val() != '' ){
                $(button).attr('href', url + $(vid).val() + '&quantity=' + $(qty).val() );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
    echo '<a href="'.$addtocart_url.'" class="'.$button_class.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';
} ```

I expect this code to work when the user does not change or update any variations on the product page. That is when the user clicks on the Buy Now button with the default variations.
````

Answer (score 0):

you don’t need all that you should add the button in the variation form it will work as submiting the form as the add to cart button then make the redirect

this is tested and working with me

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'second_button_single_variation', 30 );
   function second_button_single_variation() {
    global $product;

echo '<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="checkout_now" id="checkout_now" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt buy_now_button" value="'.$product->get_id().'">Buy Now</button></form>';
  }

  function woo_redirect_to_checkout() {
global $woocommerce;
  if( isset($_POST['checkout_now']) ){
 wc_clear_notices();
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
 wp_redirect($checkout_url);
  }
 }
    add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_to_checkout');

 // clearing the cart if you want to go to checkout with the desired product only
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart', 20, 3 );
  function remove_cart_item_before_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
if( isset($_POST['checkout_now']) ){
 if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
}
return $passed;
  }
```